# Cannot assign string[] to a function which possibly returns null

Tags: typescript

I'm using cloudflare workers KV to fetch an array of strings and concat it:

```
(await BINDING.get("upcoming", { type: "json" }) ?? []).concat(array)
```

TS doesn't know the value could be an array so it throws `Property 'concat' does not exist on type '{}'` as expected. I'm also handling the case where the value is null with `?? []`.

But when I try to add generics as `get<string>` it throws

```
Argument of type 'string | never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
```

or as `get<string[]>`

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Putting `get<any>` works but then I don't get intellisense for `concat`

Here is the type definition for `KVNamespace.get` (BINDING is of type KVNamespace) if that helps:

```
get<ExpectedValue = unknown>(
  key: Key,
  options?: KVNamespaceGetOptions<"json">
): Promise<ExpectedValue | null>;
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, then you need to cast the array to `string[]`. Example: `(await BINDING.get<string[]>("upcoming", { type: "json" }) ?? [] as string[]).concat(array)`.

Comment: @SayanPal Same error